# AngularJS radiobutton strange behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

I am trying to do simple thing: put list of my JSON objects on the form, using AngularJS.
And I want to map one of the parameters to the HTML radiobutton control. This is HTML template:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='MainController'>
    <div ng-repeat="channel in channels">
        <p>Case {{ channel.schedule.timeOfDay }}</p>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="channel.schedule.timeOfDay" ng-value="0" name="channel">Case 0</input>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="channel.schedule.timeOfDay" ng-value="1" name="channel">Case 1</input>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="channel.schedule.timeOfDay" ng-value="2" name="channel">Case 2</input>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="channel.schedule.timeOfDay" ng-value="3" name="channel">Case 3</input>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a simple controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.channels = [{
        "id": 4,
        "subject": null,
        "body": "Votre utilisation de données a atteint (SMS) [Percentage]%",
        "schedule": {
            "dayOfWeek": 24,
            "timeOfDay": 3,
            "from": 1,
            "to": 4
        },
        "channelType": 0
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "subject": null,
        "body": "Votre utilisation de données a atteint (USSD) [Percentage]%",
        "schedule": {
            "dayOfWeek": 18,
            "timeOfDay": 1,
            "from": 0,
            "to": 0
        },
        "channelType": 1
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "subject": "Avertissement",
        "body": "Votre utilisation de données a atteint (E-Mail) [Percentage]%",
        "schedule": {
            "dayOfWeek": 33,
            "timeOfDay": 3,
            "from": 15,
            "to": 22
        },
        "channelType": 2
    }]
});
```

[I created jsfiddle for this example/](http://jsfiddle.net/CYccM/25/)

So, as you can see I am mapping channel.schedule.timeOfDay to the radiobutton control, and here it come, strange behavior. The radiobutton doesnt reflect value for the first and second array elements, but do for the third. Whould someone please explain whats going on?

Comment: I expecting that for each of array elements from JSON will be selected corresponding radiobutton on the form. According to the values of timeOfDay field it should be selected Case 3, Case 1, Case 3. But as you can see from fiddle only third array elements value is reflected to the radiobutton

Comment: They're all reflected for me, it's just that since the radio buttons all share the same name, they're all part of the same group. You'll need a unique name for each set of buttons.

Comment: Oh, right, its just a group. Thank you! :)

Comment: ugh, damn you @tymeJV.. :-) i'm to slow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a bit too, change your html to: (notice the name of each option group needs to be unique)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='MainController'>
<div ng-repeat="channel in channels | orderBy:'body': false">
    <p>Case {{ channel.schedule.timeOfDay }} {{ channel.id }}</p>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="channel.schedule.timeOfDay" ng-value="0" name="t{{channel.id}}">Case 0</input>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="channel.schedule.timeOfDay" ng-value="1" name="t{{channel.id}}">Case 1</input>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="channel.schedule.timeOfDay" ng-value="2" name="t{{channel.id}}">Case 2</input>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="channel.schedule.timeOfDay" ng-value="3" name="t{{channel.id}}">Case 3</input>
    <hr>
</div>
```